# my 2D grid does not re-render while using with useState hook. Is there any way to re-render after I change object attributes of the elements inside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**Context:** I am rendering a 2-dimensional grid, where each cell is a Node object with properties: `row`, `col`, `isGood`. I create the grid and and initialize the initialGrid with a full grid.
Now I have `onClick` action that changes the property of `isGood` of clicked cell would change and it should render. However even if the change happens and the re-rendering does not happen.

Below is my code.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Node {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.row = x;
        this.col = y;
        this.isGood = false;
    }
}

const totalRows = 5;
const totalCols = 5;

var grid = [];

const createNodes = () => {
    grid = [];
    for (let row = 0; row < totalRows; ++row) {
        var newRow = [];
        for (let col = 0; col < totalCols; ++col) {
            newRow.push(new Node(row, col));
        }
        grid.push(newRow);
    }
    console.log(grid);
};

createNodes();

const App = () => {
    const [initialGrid, setGrid] = useState(grid);

    const handleClick = (rowIndex, colIndex) => {
        initialGrid[rowIndex][colIndex].isGood = true;
        setGrid(initialGrid);
    };

    const getNodeClass = (node) => {
        const newClassName = node.isGood === true ? "node-good" : "node";
        return newClassName;
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {initialGrid.map((row, rowIndex) => {
                return (
                    <div key={rowIndex} className="rows">
                        {row.map((column, columnIndex) => {
                            return (
                                <div
                                    className={getNodeClass(column)}
                                    id={`${rowIndex}-${columnIndex}`}
                                    key={columnIndex}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        handleClick(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                                    }}
                                ></div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

How can I re-render the grid ?

my `onClick` works and I can see it on `console.log` however the re-rendering doesnot happen even if I call `setGrid`

Comment: `initialGrid[rowIndex][colIndex].isGood = true;`. Here `initialGrid` refers to the same state reference. try setting state using spread syntax. It will work

Comment: @ShivamJha   Thanks for reply.   I tried this by doing something like 
`const handleClick = (rowIndex, colIndex) => {
        let newGrid = { ...initialGrid };
        newGrid[rowIndex][colIndex].isGood = true;
        console.log(newGrid);
        setGrid(newGrid);
    };
`
It fails with error `initialGrid.map is not a function`. I cant figure out the proper use of spread operator and what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: [Create a new Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) with just minimal code to demonstrate your problem, and I can edit there and help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct a **new array** in the call to setGrid or React won't realize it needs to re-render.  You can do this with the spread operator, adding the individual elements of the old array to your new array:

```
const handleClick = (rowIndex, colIndex) => {
    initialGrid[rowIndex][colIndex].isGood = true;
    setGrid([...initialGrid]);
};
```

We're also told React works better if we make the call to setGrid into a function as below, which also works.  Personally I'm not sure if this is strictly necessary in this example and the code is arguably less clear:

```
const handleClick = (rowIndex, colIndex) => {
    initialGrid[rowIndex][colIndex].isGood = true;
    setGrid((ary) => [...ary]);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand how I was supposed to use the spread operator. I don't have enough reputation to upvote. But it is the solution I was looking for. And for setGrid to make work on a functional basis, a quick search does provide links to articles on why it's better. I would go through it when I get time. But that is also interesting to know.